# Redmine feature to configure multiple target versions for each ticket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

In [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), I need an alternate to the `Target Version` field in a ticket. Basically, I would like to pre-define a large number of version numbers and then assign more than 1 version number to a ticket. For example a ticket can be assigned `Software 1.2.0` and `Hardware 1.1.0`. The `List` Format for a `Custom Field` will not work because you can only choose one at a time. I'd rather not create checkboxes either because the number of checkboxes will become huge. Any ideas?

I also posted [this ticket on the official Redmine forum](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/15074)

Thanks! Chirag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have a similar wish, but I don't have a great solution.

One workaround is to combine the two target versions (like: Software 1.2.0 / Hardware 1.1.0), for me that usually is good enough for what I need to do.
Another option would be to take your issue, and create two child issues inside of it, each with its own target version.

Comment: So here you are using Redmine as a project management tool. I would say that this means that you have to split the one issue to two more detailed issues anyway. Because you probably have to define tasks for the two different components (software, hardware) which are not the same. So I would also suggest to create two sub issues.

Comment: In my case, which isn't software and hardware, I make a change to a component that is shared in 2 separate systems.  So, the task is the same, but is released into 2 separate installsets, and these installsets are essentially "target versions".  So, I combine the 2 installset versions into one target version to make it work well in Redmine.